# Turn on vs Come on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm reading a book *Key Words For Fluency* and I found there a topic about heating. There are two sentences:

Turn the heating on/off.

Set the heating to come on at 5 and go off at 9.

Could you explain to me the difference between these phrasal verbs (turn on/off and come on/goes off) in such context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of machines or systems such as heating systems, computers, etc, the difference is that a person turns a machine on or off, but a machine can come on or go off by itself (e.g. if it has a time switch). Electricity in a house can go off if there is a power failure and come (back) on again later.

To turn something on in this context means to make it work by pressing a switch, pulling a lever, etc.

> Definition of turn on
> transitive verb
> 1: to activate or cause to flow, operate, or function by or as if by turning a control
> *turn the water on full*
> *turn on the power*

[Turn on (Merriam Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20on)

In this context also, if something

comes on, it starts working

> Come on
> phrasal verb
> to start to happen or work
> *The heating comes on at six in the morning*

[Come on (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-on)

Comment: So the difference is in the way it starts working. Turn on - by a human; Come on - by itself. Thank you.

Comment: @BBQBoi That's correct. You will sometimes hear "Turn itself on" instead of "Come on". That is a valid expression too.